# Left join with ServiceStack.OrmLite returns an empty object instead of null

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I've created [a repository with a complete example of what I'm trying to do](https://github.com/jennings/so-46534884).

I have the following schema:

```
class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

class LineItem
{
    public int LineItemId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using ServiceStack.OrmLite to left join Order with LineItem, using this code:

```
var query = db.From<Order>()
              .LeftJoin<LineItem>()
              .Where(o => o.OrderId == 1);

var results = db.SelectMulti<Order, LineItem>(query);
```

`SelectMulti()` returns a `List<Tuple<Order, LineItem>>`. When an order has no line items, I'm getting back `new LineItem()` instead of `null`.

I expected to get `null` back so I could tell the difference between "no line items exist for this order" and "this order has a line item with default values".

I *could* check for the line item's `OrderId` being equal to the order's `OrderId`, but in theory I could have an order with `OrderId` 0, so in that case I wouldn't be able to tell.

Is there a better way to do this left join with OrmLite?

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution I used was to check whether the related objects returned were "empty".

I did that with a small inline function as follows:

```
bool IsEmptyObject<T>(T instance)
{
    var empty = Activator.CreateInstance(instance.GetType());
    return empty.ToJson() == instance.ToJson();
}
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient, `Activator.CreateInstance()` is slow when not cached and this allocates a new instance everytime. `instance.GetType().GetDefaultValue().ToJson() == instance.ToJson()` is more efficient, although if your Type is a struct or overrides `Equals()` it would be more efficient to use `instance.GetType().GetDefaultValue().Equals(instance)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I expected to get null back so I could tell the difference between "no line items exist for this order" and "this order has a line item with default values".

The issue with LEFT JOIN is that the row does exist but all fields are returned as `null` which OrmLite maps to an instance where no fields are initialized which is indistinguishable from a row that doesn't exist.

> I could check for the line item's OrderId being equal to the order's OrderId, but in theory I could have an order with OrderId 0, so in that case I wouldn't be able to tell.

This should not be possible as Auto Incrementing Primary Keys start at 1 (by default) and increment upwards. You should consider it invalid state (which is likely an indication it was added incorrectly) if you have an `int` primary key with `0` so checking against `default(int)` should suffice.

Comment: Regarding the PK, there are valid situations for a PK not to be auto-incrementing, or the DBA could have chosen to start at 0 instead of 1. It's valid for OrmLite to choose not to support these situations, since they are uncommon, but the situations do exist.

Comment: If the model has non-nullable fields but the database returns a null in that column, especially if it's a primary key, that's a pretty good indication that there were no rows on the right side of the join. I realize OrmLite does not interrogate the database to know with certainty if the column is nullable, but the .NET property being non-nullable could be a good heuristic. (Aside, I have looked at OrmLite's implementation and I see why this would be difficult to implement without a lot of refactoring.)

Comment: @StephenJennings yeah if all fields were null and the resultset includes the PrimaryKey we could assume `null` instead of an empty object. It's technically possible but I don't imagine a scenario where it would be "valid" for an Order to have a `0` PK.

Comment: A contrived example: If the table were `UnixUsers` instead of `Orders`, then root would probably have a PK of 0.

Comment: @StephenJennings A UnixUsers table wouldn't have an Auto Incrementing Id.